# Fixed number of trials in binomial distribution

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution

What is meant by the condition for a binomial distribution that the number of trials must be fixed?

Does this mean the number of trials must be fixed *before* the experiment?

Comment: Could you provide the whole quote that is unclear for you..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to comment without further details, but your question can be given a general answer.

[Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) describes the number of successes $k$ in $n$ trials, where the probability of success is $p$. So you have a fixed $n$ and $p$, i.e. they are parameters of your distribution and are not random. If you needed a distribution where the number of trials is also a random variable, you would have to define it in terms of a compound distribution rather then using simple binomial model. Another example of varying $n$ is a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), where you stop your experiment after seeing $r$ failures -- so the sample size is not specified at start.